# Obtener valores de una consulta linq C#

Tags: c#, linq

Mi problema es que necesito extraer los valores del usuario que esta ingresando al sistema Ejemplo del usuario Juan necesito conocer su nombre apellido(Esto esta en la tabla Usuarios) y codigo(Esta es de otra tabla llamada roles). Y los valores que voy a extraer los voy almacenar en una variable Global en una clase llamada Global.

**Esta es la capa Logica del proyecto en este metodo valido si el usuario existe en la base de datos**

```
public bool Login(Usuario_E Vusuario)
    {
        using (programacion_ii_c db = new programacion_ii_c())
        {
            try
            {
                var qw = (from u in db.Usuarios
                          join x in db.Roles
                          on u.IdUsuario equals x.IdRol
                          where (Vusuario.Usuario == u.Usuario 
                          && Vusuario.ContraseÒa == u.Contrasena)

                          select new
                          {
                              Nombres = u.Nombres,
                              Usuario = u.Usuario,
                              IdUsuario = u.IdUsuario,
                              IdRol = x.IdRol,
                              Rol = x.Nombre,
                              Codigo = x.Codigo
                          });

                if (qw.ToList().Count > 0)
                {
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return false;
                throw ex;
            }
        }
    }
```

**Este es la capa presentacion en el formulario FrmLogin en el boton ingresar**

```
private void btnlogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (TxtUsuario.Text != "Usuario")
        {
            if (TxtContraseÒa.Text != "Contrasena")
            {
                Usuario_E usuario = new Usuario_E();
                usuario.Usuario = TxtUsuario.Text;
                usuario.ContraseÒa = TxtContraseÒa.Text;
                usuario.Nombres = Global.Nombre;
                usuario.Apellidos = Global.Apellido;
                usuario.Codigo = Global.Apellido;
                Rol_E Rol = new Rol_E();
                Usuario_L acceso = new Usuario_L();
                var validacion = acceso.Login(usuario);

                if (validacion == true)
                {
                    DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Usuario o contraseÒa incorrecta", "Revise", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error de contrasena", "ERROR", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error usuario", "ERROR", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);

        }
    }
```

**CLASE GLOBAL SE ENCUENTRA EN LA CAPA PRESENTACION**

```
public class Global
{
    public static  string Nombre { get; set; }
    public static string Apellido { get; set; }
    public static string CodigoRol { get; set; }
}
```

}

Comment: create un metodo nuevo el cual obtengas esos valores, y cuando se cumpla la validacion `if (validacion == true)` mandas a llamar el metodo nuevo para obtener los datos del usuario.

Answer (score 1):

Si lo que necesitas es crear una clase Global con los datos del usuario, en la consulta podes crearla y retornarla para lo que necesites a partir del id de usuario, algo asi:

```
        public Global GetGlobalByIdUser(int id) {

        var qw = from usuario in db.Usuarios
                 join rol in db.Roles
                 on usuario.IdUsuario equals rol.IdRol
                 where usuario.IdUsuario == id
                 select new Global {
                     Nombre = usuario.Nombre,
                     Apellido = usuario.Apellido,
                     CodigoRol = rol.Codigo
                 };

                  return qw.FirstOrDefault();
    }
```